# What is a better Tkinter geometry manager than .grid()

Tags: python, tkinter

**My Complaint**

I am currently delving deeper than "ever" before into the Tkinter GUI, and I have found the `.grid()` geometry manager to be inadequate for several reasons:

1. The plots are based on the largest widget within them - this relativity leads to inaccuracy.
2. In Windows 7, on Python 2.7.3, the program does not seem to heed my row numbers, instead preferring to use the order of the widgets.

**My Code**

I am currently working on a *really* basic text editor, and I want to have multiple buttons on the top of the frame. I have been unable to do this as my widgets are placed either to the far left or right of the massive textbox that dominates the center of the screen.

```
========Class __init__ Stuff============
def widget(self):#Place widgets here

    #Save Button
    self.saveButton = Button (self, text = "Save", command = self.saveMe)
    self.saveButton.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = W)

    #Open Button
    self.openButton = Button (self, text = "Open", command = self.openMe)
    self.openButton.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = W)
    #Area where you write 
    self.text = Text (self, width = (root.winfo_screenwidth() - 20),
                      height = (root.winfo_screenheight() - 10))
    self.text.grid(row = 2)
==============Mainloop/Command Stuff============
```

**My Question**

Is there another way to use the `.grid()` geometry manager in a way that is more accurate, or should I be using another function altogether?

Thanks!

Comment: Your comment about windows not "heeding your row numbers" is incorrect. The grid geometry manager has been proven to be 100% functional on all platforms for a couple of decades. I'm not saying your code isn't misbehaving, it's just not misbehaving for the reasons you think it is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are 3 geometry managers that you have available to you -- `grid`, `pack` and `place`.  The third is the most general, but also very difficult to use.  I prefer `grid`.  Note that you can place widgets inside of other widgets -- Or you can specify `columnspan`.  So, if you want to get the following layout:

```
  -------------------------
  |    Button1  | Button2 |
  -------------------------
  |     Big Widget        |
  -------------------------
```

there are 2 canonical ways to do it using `.grid`.  The first method is `columnspan`:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
root = Tk.Tk()
b1 = Tk.Button(root,text="Button1")
b1.grid(row=0,column=0)
b2 = Tk.Button(root,text="Button2")
b2.grid(row=0,column=1)
big_widget = Tk.Canvas(root)
big_widget.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2)
```

*note that there is a completely analogous `rowspan` option as well.

The second method is to use a `Frame` to hold your buttons:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
root = Tk.Tk()
f = Tk.Frame(root)
f.grid(row=0,column=0)
#place buttons on the *frame*
b1 = Tk.Button(f,text="Button1")
b1.grid(row=0,column=0)
b2 = Tk.Button(f,text="Button2")
b2.grid(row=0,column=1)

big_widget = Tk.Canvas(root)
big_widget.grid(row=1,column=0)  #don't need columnspan any more.
```

This method is **SUPER** useful for creating complex layouts -- I don't know how you could create a complex layout without using `Frame` objects like this ...

Comment: Ok.... So you are using Tk.Canvas instead of Tk.Text, correct? Also, how would you use .place() and why is it the most general/accurate (The meaning was ambiguous to me)

Comment: with `.place`, you specify the exact coordinates where you want to put the widget.  As far as I'm concerned, that one would be a maintenance **nightmare** and is hardly worth mentioning. -- And yes, I'm saying `Canvas` instead of `Text` -- I just needed to choose a widget which usually takes a lot more space than `Button` widgets do ;-)

Comment: +1 - in my experience with lots of different GUI toolkits and geometry managers, using a really simple layout manager and nest the different groups works by far the best. All those more complicated geometries (I'm talking of you Swing and all your different managers) are harder to use and don't really give you anything you can't get with the nesting approach.

Comment: @Voo -- I can't say about any other GUI toolkits -- I only know Tkinter -- But this has been my workhorse and I can't see any better way to do it.

Comment: @mgilson One (several) more question(s) before you go. How would I create multiple frames using OOP? Do I need to initialize a new class, or a new method? Lastly, for widgets within this new frame, how should I place them within one frame - not the other? Lastly, in your opinion, is Tkinter a strong enough GUI for use on larger projects, or is it simply a learning tool for a beginner such as I? You've been incredibly helpful - thank you so much! :)

Comment: As far as how to do it using OOP -- I don't know.  I don't obsess too much about using OOP or not using it.  I just try to get the code working in a way that makes sense to me and work to clean the interface as much as possible.  It really pays to sit down and figure out how you want the pieces to interact -- Then, once you've figured out how the data should be passed around the program it's usually easier to design the GUI.  I think you can use `Tkinter` for bigger projects.  I know Bryan Oakley would agree -- but others would disagree.  Bigger projects often use gtk/wxWidgets for example.

Answer (score 7):

The "best" geometry manager depends on what you want to do, no geometry manager is best for all situations. For what you're trying to do in this specific case, pack is probably the better choice. Also note that there may be more than one "best" in an application. It's quite normal to use both grid and pack in different parts of your applications. I rarely ever create a GUI where I don't use both grid and pack. And rarely, I also use place.

pack excels at placing things in single rows and single columns. Toolbars, for example, are a perfect case for using pack since you want all your buttons aligned to the left. grid, as it name implies, is best when you want fixed rows and columns. place is useful in those rare cases where neither grid nor pack will do, since it allows you to place widgets at precise fixed or relative locations.

My advice is to divide your application widgets into groups, and use the right geometry manager for each group. In your case you have two logical groups: the toolbar along the top, and a text-widget-and-scrollbar combination in the bottom. So, start with two frames. Since the toolbar is on top and the text widget is below, pack works best.

```
toolbar = tk.Frame(...)
main = tk.Frame(...)
toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
main.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
```

The above now gives you two areas that are easy to modify independently.

For the toolbar, pack is again most natural. In this case, however, you want the buttons along the left instead of along the top or bottom:

```
b1 = tk.Button(toolbar, ...)
b2 = tk.Button(toolbar, ...)
b1.pack(side="left")
b2.pack(side="left")
...
```

Finally, the bottom area. Your example code doesn't show scrollbars, but I assume at some point you'll want to add them. grid works well if you're using both horizontal and vertical scrollbars. I would lay them out like this:

```
hsb = tk.Scrollbar(main, ..., orient="horizontal", ...)
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(main, ..., orient="vertical", ...)
text = tk.Text(main, ...)
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
hsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
main.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
main.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

That last part is important -- you always need to give a weight to at least one row and one column. This tells grid which rows and columns should grow and shrink when the window is resized.

Answer (score 1):

I find the `place` manager the most intuitive and accurate of all three, because of the possibility to specify combinations of absolute and relative lengths for both positions and size:

```py
mywidget.place(x=..., y=..., width=..., height=...) # absolute
mywidget.place(relx=..., rely=..., relwidth=..., relheight=...) # relative

# combination
pad_left=5
pad_right=5
pad_top=5
pad_bottom=5
mywidget.place(relx=0, x=pad_left, rely=0, y=pad_top,\
       relwidth=1, width=-pad_left-pad_right,\
       relheight=1, height=-pad_top-pad_bottom, anchor="e") # use the whole space except some padding
```

For some reason, the `.place` manager doesn't seem very liked, but I find it makes a particulary good job to define how your widgets should move around and resize when the parent window is resized.

To ease the construction of complex windows, I sometimes use a function (to kind of emulate a grid behaviour I suppose) to aid in the vertical placement, such as:

```py
def offset_y(line_no):
    if line_no == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return height_label + (line_no - 1)*height_button

mylabel.place(..., y=offset_y(0))
mybtn1.place(..., y=offset_y(1))
etc.
```

to pack vertically a Label and then a series of buttons. (Of course, the `.pack` manager could be used in this case, but the reason I prefer the `.place` manager is for understanding more accurately how things will move around when the window is resized).

Comment: I don't understand your comments about accuracy. For example, when I use pack and grid, I know precisely how they are going to behave. How is place any more accurate in that regard? As for why most people don't use place, it's likely due to it simply being more complicated: it requires you to do a lot of the math yourself. Both pack and grid take care of most of the math for you.

Comment: I suppose what I like about `place` is simply the coordinate system. @Bryan Oakley: accurate in that sense: I know exactly where I put my widget and which size I give it in either absolute or relative coordinates within the Frame. I can add all my widgets like that. What I don't particularly like about `pack` is the need of a hierarchy of invisible `Frame`s to group widgets. What I don't particulary like about `grid` is to have to use 'buffer' (invisible) rows/columns to provide extensible 'padding' when window resizing should move the widgets but not modify their size. But maybe I missed sth?

Answer (score -2):

Instead of row,column....etc.,you can use coordinates.

It may be easier than the others.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
from Tkinter import*
root=Tk()
Button(root,text="HI").grid(padx=100,pady=50)
root.mainloop()
```

Try it youself by changing padx and pady values.