# How to place widgets into different frames in Tkinter, using OOP

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

**Background**

Hello everyone! I am currently working on a basic GUI text editor which can load and save text files. I want to use multiple frames for the toolbar and the textbox as I learned [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846063/what-is-a-better-tkinter-geometry-manager-than-grid) I am using OOP, and have set up my frames in the `__init__` method, and the widgets in the `widget` method. For some reason, the widgets are unable to be placed within their respective Frames.

**Code**

```
from Tkinter import *
class Application:
    def __init__(self,parent):  #initialize the grid and widgets
        self.myParent = parent

        #Init the toolbar
        self.toolbar = Frame(parent)
        self.toolbar.grid(row = 0)

        #Init frame for the text box

        self.mainframe = Frame(parent)
        self.toolbar.grid(row = 1)
    def widget(self):#Place widgets here

        #Save Button
        self.saveButton = Button (self, self.toolbar,
                                  text = "Save", command = self.saveMe)
        self.saveButton.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = W)

        #Open Button
        self.openButton = Button (self, self.toolbar,
                                 text = "Open", command = self.openMe)
        self.openButton.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = W)
        #Area where you write 
        self.text = Text (self, self.mainframe,
                          width = (root.winfo_screenwidth() - 20),
                          height = (root.winfo_screenheight() - 10))
       self.text.grid(row = 2)
```

**Questions**

1. Still using different methods, how can I make sure that each widget is placed in the correct Frame?

   - If this is not possible, please just show me how to do it using OOP - I am most comfortable with Tkinter in that setting and have promised myself to improve.
2. Please *explain* your answer. I *need* to cognate - not simply nod my head at the computer and go right along.
3. Extra Credit: How would I initialize multiple windows (each window being a different class) using Tkinter in OOP? For instance, if this was my code:

   ```
   class MainWindow(Frame):
       ---init stuff---
       def widget(self):
           newWindow = Button(self, text = "click for a new window",
                              command = self.window)
           newWindow.grid()
      def window(self):
            #What would I put in here to initialize the new window??

   class theNextWindow(Frame):
   ```

   What would I put in the `window.self` method to make the `theNextWindow` window visible?

Thanks for everyone's help!

**EDIT 1**

I added the line `self.widget()` in the `__init__` method, and I was rewarded with this "wonderful" error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python Programs\Text Editor\MyTextv2.py", line 67, in <module>
 app = Application(root)
File "D:\Python Programs\Text Editor\MyTextv2.py", line 14, in __init__
 self.widget()
File "D:\Python Programs\Text Editor\MyTextv2.py", line 24, in widget
 text = "Save", command = self.saveMe)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2044, in __init__
 Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1965, in __init__
 BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1943, in _setup
 self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: Application instance has no attribute 'tk'
```

As the error log clearly references my mainloop here: `File "D:\Python Programs\Text Editor\MyTextv2.py", line 67, in <module>
     app = Application(root)` I decided to add it:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("My Text Editor")

#This is wierd - it gets the computer windows dimensions
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.overrideredirect(0)

#And then applies them here
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now? If the code generates an error, please include the text of the error in your question. Also, as a matter of style, `widget` is not a very good name for a method. Methods *do* things, a good method name indicates what the method does. A better name for `widget()` would be `setUpWidgets()` or `setUpWindow()`.

Comment: The code does not generate an error, it is a logical problem. The window is simply empty and grey - obviously not very helpful!

Comment: In your code you never call `.widget()`, so none of the code within that method gets executed. Where's the code to run all of this stuff?

Comment: @JoelCornett Thanks for the suggestion. I added it, and I got a great error message... Also, why do you think that `widget()` is not a great name? PS: This is a n00b question: how do I do the code-quotes on Windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *finally* found the answer. From what I have found (feel free to edit this if it is wrong) is that there are only two ways that a `Frame` can be inherited in Tkinter: from the class itself and from the method that a widget is currently in. To solve the issue, I set up the class `Application` as a frame, and then place other frames within it. Here is a basic rendition of what I did:

```
#Import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

#Main Frame
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):  #initialize the grid and widgets
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.redFUN() #initialize the red frame's Function
        self.greenFUN() #initialize the green frame's Function
        self.widgets() #To show that you can still place non-Frame widgets 
    def widgets(self):
        self.mylabel = Label (self, text = "Hello World!")
        self.mylabel.grid()
    def redFUN(self): #The 'self' means that it is an instance of the main frame
        #Init the red frame
        self.redFrame = Frame(root, width = 100, height = 50,pady = 5,
                              bg = "red")
        self.redFrame.grid()



    def greenFUN(self): #Child of the mainframe
        self.greenFrame = Frame(root, width = 100, height = 50,pady = 5,
                          bg = "green") #it is green!
        self.greenFrame.grid()








#These lines of code are used for the grid
root = Tk()
root.title("Frame Example")
root.geometry("300x300")
app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I hope this helps everyone - if you have any questions, feel free to comment!

Comment: You wrote in a comment `#The 'self' means that it is the child of the main frame`. That is incorrect. `self` means that it is an instance method - one that belongs to an instance of the class rather than the class. The term "child" doesn't apply in this situation.

Comment: Was there any misinformation here? What was the reason for the -1?

Comment: When downvoting, please explain why and suggest a reason for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1:

A widget can only have one immediate parent. There's no syntax for passing in two parents. You seem to be passing in both `self` and `self.toolbar` as parents of `self.saveButton`, for example.

```
myButton = Button(self.toolbar, text="Blah", command=self.someCommand)
```

is the form you should use.

Problem 2:

Let's say that you instead wanted `Application` (AKA the `self` in `Button(self, self.toolbar...)`) to be the parent of `myButton`. This won't work either, because in order to be the hierarchical parent of a Tk widget, a class must also be an instance of `Widget`. Usually, what you do if you want this is to inherit `tk.Tk()` in `Application` as follows:

```
class Application(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):


        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) #It's important that you call the parent class's __init__ method first

        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):

        self.myButton = Button(self, text="Blah", command=lambda x: print "x")
        #this is ok, because now self (AKA Application) is a valid instance of Tk
```