# Tk Canvas Usage in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

There is a post of this code, posted by mgilson, that I don't understand. All up to the reference to `big_widget` makes sense. But, what does the reference to `big_widget` contribute? The particular post [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846063/what-is-a-better-tkinter-geometry-manager-than-grid). I am trying to refine my code and, I think, use the `Frame` object. But, the reference to `Canvas` threw me. I tried to comment but I need 50+ reputation to do so. Not there yet.

```
import Tkinter as Tk
root = Tk.Tk()
f = Tk.Frame(root)
f.grid(row=0,column=0)
#place buttons on the *frame*
b1 = Tk.Button(f,text="Button1")
b1.grid(row=0,column=0)
b2 = Tk.Button(f,text="Button2")
b2.grid(row=0,column=1)

big_widget = Tk.Canvas(root)
big_widget.grid(row=1,column=0)  #don't need columnspan any more.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> big_widget = Tk.Canvas(root)
>   --> A Canvas object is initialized, anchored to root and assigned to big_widget

The next line places the canvas (big_widget) at row=1 column=0 on the grid

(in the same way, a frame (f) was previously initialized and placed at row=0 column=0 on the grid inside root)

Comment: Yes, I understand what big_widget is. What I don't understand is how it relates to the Tk.Frame object. What purpose does it serve being created when the buttons were created on the previously created Frame?

Comment: It really doesn't relate to the f frame, outside of the fact that it is in root and placed alongside of it. big_widget can be used to draw or hold other widgets like any canvas widget... f can be used to hold other widgets as well (buttons, etc...) - Don't overthink this, you have a root with two widgets, a frame and a canvas; they have different properties that you can use the way you like. :) Of course, you can have them interact, but you don't have to.

Comment: TNX for the response. "It really doesn't relate"... is what I thought. In other words, those two snippets of code could be deleted and not have any effect on the answer to the original question posted. That is what I thought. Again, TNX for your comments -- much appreciated.