# set the correct Tkinter widgets position in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

i am writing a GUI for a RAW image converter in Python using Tkinter. The GUI is divide in three part. The part A has a button to import the RAW file, the part B has four Checkbuttons, and the part C has Checkbuttons with two Entry spaces.

[image]

The length of the columns 0 (= the first) is given by the label "correct chromatic aberration" (the longest element). This mean if i change the name for example in correct chromatic aberration for white balance" all elements are shifted as the image below, and the part A, B, and C are related each other.

[image]

I wish to make independent the part A to the part B, and so on, in order to have the below image. In other words i wish to place each block of buttons into their own frame, and the frames in the main window.

[image]

the original code is:

```
from __future__ import division
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import tkFileDialog

class MainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("FOO converter")
        self.master.minsize(350, 150)
        self.grid(sticky=E+W+N+S)

        self.save_dir = None
        self.filename_open = None

        top = self.winfo_toplevel()
        top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.CHART_FILE_TYPES = [('Pentax Electronic Format', '*.pef'),
                                ('Sony Alpha Raw', '*.arw'),
                                ('Minolta Raw', '*.mrw'),
                                ('Camera Image File Format', '*.crw'),
                                ('Canon Raw', '*.cr2'),
                                ('Epson Raw', '*.erw'),
                                ('Samsung Raw', '*.srw'),
                                ('Fujifilm Raw', '*.raf'),
                                ('Kodak Digital Camera Raw', '*.dcr'),
                                ('Nikon Electronic Format', '*.nef'),
                                ('Olympus Raw', '*.orf'),
                                ('All files', '.*')]

        for i in range(10): self.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.open = Button(self, text='Input raw image file', command=self.open, activeforeground="red")
        self.open.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        self.sep = Frame(self, height=2, width=450, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN)
        self.sep.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.CheckVar_camera_white_balance = IntVar()
        self.CheckVar_camera_white_balance = Checkbutton(self,
            text="Camera white balance",
            variable=self.CheckVar_camera_white_balance,
            onvalue=1,
            offvalue=0)
        self.CheckVar_camera_white_balance.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=0, padx=0, sticky=W)

        self.CheckVar_average_whole_image_white_balance = IntVar()
        self.CheckVar_average_whole_image_white_balance = Checkbutton(self,
            text="Average the whole image for white balance",
            variable=self.CheckVar_average_whole_image_white_balance,
            onvalue=1,
            offvalue=0)
        self.CheckVar_average_whole_image_white_balance.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=0, padx=0, sticky=W)

        self.CheckVar_correct_chromatic_aberration = IntVar()
        self.CheckVar_correct_chromatic_aberration = Checkbutton(self,
            text="Correct chromatic aberration",
            variable=self.CheckVar_correct_chromatic_aberration,
            onvalue=1,
            offvalue=0)
        self.CheckVar_correct_chromatic_aberration.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=0, padx=0, sticky=W)

        self.CheckVar_fix_dead_pixels = IntVar()
        self.CheckVar_fix_dead_pixels = Checkbutton(self,
            text="Fix dead pixels",
            variable=self.CheckVar_fix_dead_pixels,
            onvalue=1,
            offvalue=0)
        self.CheckVar_fix_dead_pixels.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=0, padx=0, sticky=W)

        self.sep = Frame(self, height=2, width=450, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN)
        self.sep.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.CheckVar_brightness = IntVar()
        self.CheckVar_brightness = Checkbutton(self, text="Brightness",
            command=self.switch_brightness,
            variable=self.CheckVar_brightness,
            onvalue=1,
            offvalue=0)
        self.CheckVar_brightness.grid(row=7, column=0, pady=0, padx=2, sticky=W)

        self.label_level_brightness = Label(self, text="Brightness level:", state=DISABLED)
        self.label_level_brightness.grid(row=8, column=0, pady=0, padx=0, sticky=W)

        self.entry_level_brightness = Entry(self, state=DISABLED)
        self.entry_level_brightness.grid(row=8, column=1, pady=0, padx=0, sticky=W)

        self.label_gamma_curve = Label(self, text="Gamma curve:", state=DISABLED)
        self.label_gamma_curve.grid(row=9, column=0, pady=0, padx=0, sticky=W)

        self.entry_gamma_curve_1 = Entry(self, state=DISABLED)
        self.entry_gamma_curve_1.grid(row=9, column=1, pady=0, padx=0, sticky=W)

        self.entry_gamma_curve_2 = Entry(self, state=DISABLED)
        self.entry_gamma_curve_2.grid(row=9, column=2, pady=0, padx=0, sticky=E+W+N+S)


# functions

    def open(self):
        self.filename_open = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=self.CHART_FILE_TYPES, defaultextension='.*')

    def switch_brightness(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
   d = MainWindow()
   d.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am not very well versed with tkinter, but in this case, you probably want to place each block of buttons into their own frame, and the frames in the main window.

Comment: This post might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846063/what-is-a-better-tkinter-geometry-manager-than-grid

Comment: Example : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/GUI-Tk/Gridlayoutmanagerdemonstration.htm

Answer (score 2):

If you want the regions to be independent, use a frame for each region. For example:

```
top_frame = Frame(self, ...)
middle_frame = Frame(self, ...)
bottom_frame = Frame(self, ...)

top_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
middle_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
bottom_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```

With that, you can now treat each region independently. This now affords you the luxury of using different geometry managers for different sections. You may want to use `pack` in the top and middle frame, and grid in the lower frame.

```
# Top frame
self.open = Button(top_frame, ...)
self.open.pack(side="left")
...
# Middle frame
self.CheckVar_camera_white_balance = Checkbutton(middle_frame, ...)
self.CheckVar_camera_white_balance.pack(side="top", fill="x")
...
# Bottom frame
self.CheckVar_brightness = Checkbutton(bottom_frame, ...)
self.CheckVar_brightness.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=0, padx=2, sticky=W)
...
```

Comment: the self.CheckVar_brightness = Checkbutton(self, ...) is self.CheckVar_brightness = Checkbutton(bottom_frame , ...)?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am honest to say it's not for me (sorry) very clear but it's a good help