# improve Frame of Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, frame

I am quite new to use Frame of Tkinter in Python. I discovered Frame from the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198849/set-the-correct-tkinter-widgets-position-in-python) 
When i run the GUI the Check box are not in the same line.

[image]

For this reason i have the following two questions:

1) is it possible to use "grid" in the frame in order to place the widget where i wish?

2) Is it possible to place for example "Camera white balance" and "average white balance" in the same row? in grid is for example row=0, column=0 and row=0, column=1

3) if i add a line below the button "Input raw image file" using the code:

```
self.sep = Frame(self, height=2, width=450, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN)
self.sep.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=5, pady=5)
```

The Run works forever without showing the GUI.

My code is:

```
from __future__ import division
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import tkFileDialog


class MainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("FOO frame")
        self.master.minsize(350, 150)
        self.grid(sticky=W+N+S+E)

        top_frame = Frame(self)
        middle_frame = Frame(self)
        bottom_frame = Frame(self)

        top_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        middle_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        bottom_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        self.open = Button(top_frame,text="Input raw image file",
                           command=self.open,
                           activeforeground="red")
        self.open.pack(side="left")

        self.CheckVar_camera_white_balance = IntVar()
        self.CheckVar_camera_white_balance = Checkbutton(middle_frame,
            text="Camera white balance",
            variable=self.CheckVar_camera_white_balance,
            onvalue=1,
            offvalue=0)
        self.CheckVar_camera_white_balance.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        self.CheckVar_average_whole_image_white_balance = IntVar()
        self.CheckVar_average_whole_image_white_balance = Checkbutton(middle_frame,
            text="Average white balance",
            variable=self.CheckVar_average_whole_image_white_balance,
            onvalue=1,
            offvalue=0)
        self.CheckVar_average_whole_image_white_balance.pack()

        self.CheckVar_correct_chromatic_aberration = IntVar()
        self.CheckVar_correct_chromatic_aberration = Checkbutton(middle_frame,
            text="Correct chromatic aberration",
            variable=self.CheckVar_correct_chromatic_aberration,
            onvalue=1,
            offvalue=0)
        self.CheckVar_correct_chromatic_aberration.pack()

        self.CheckVar_fix_dead_pixels = IntVar()
        self.CheckVar_fix_dead_pixels = Checkbutton(middle_frame,
            text="Fix dead pixels",
            variable=self.CheckVar_fix_dead_pixels,
            onvalue=1,
            offvalue=0)
        self.CheckVar_fix_dead_pixels.pack()


# functions

    def open(self):
        self.filename_open = tkFileDialog.askopenfilenames(defaultextension='.*')

if __name__ == "__main__":
   d = MainWindow()
   d.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, you can certainly do what you want with grid.  Just realize that if you grid some of the children of middle_frame, you have to grid them all.  You can mix gridding and packing within the same widget.

Comment: Thanks i know it's possible. Do you have also some example?

Comment: I don't have time to write one just at the moment, but I think you'll find good examples at http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Answers to your Questions Bryan Oakley gave you. Here is some code so you can imagine what he is talking about:

```
from __future__ import division

from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import tkMessageBox
from ttk import Separator


class MainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("FOO frame")
        self.master.minsize(350, 150)
        self.grid(sticky=W+N+S+E)

        top_frame = Frame(self)
        middle_frame = Frame(self)
        bottom_frame = Frame(self)

        top_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        middle_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        bottom_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        self.open = Button(top_frame,text="Input raw image file",
                           command=self.open,
                           activeforeground="red")
        self.open.pack(side="left")

        self.sep = Separator(middle_frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.sep.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="WE", pady=5)

        self.CheckVar_camera_white_balance = IntVar()
        self.CheckVar_camera_white_balance = Checkbutton(middle_frame,
            text="Camera white balance",
            variable=self.CheckVar_camera_white_balance,
            onvalue=1,
            offvalue=0)
        self.CheckVar_camera_white_balance.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="W")

        self.CheckVar_average_whole_image_white_balance = IntVar()
        self.CheckVar_average_whole_image_white_balance = Checkbutton(middle_frame,
            text="Average white balance",
            variable=self.CheckVar_average_whole_image_white_balance,
            onvalue=1,
            offvalue=0)
        self.CheckVar_average_whole_image_white_balance.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="W")

        self.CheckVar_correct_chromatic_aberration = IntVar()
        self.CheckVar_correct_chromatic_aberration = Checkbutton(middle_frame,
            text="Correct chromatic aberration",
            variable=self.CheckVar_correct_chromatic_aberration,
            onvalue=1,
            offvalue=0)
        self.CheckVar_correct_chromatic_aberration.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="W")

        self.CheckVar_fix_dead_pixels = IntVar()
        self.CheckVar_fix_dead_pixels = Checkbutton(middle_frame,
            text="Fix dead pixels",
            variable=self.CheckVar_fix_dead_pixels,
            onvalue=1,
            offvalue=0)
        self.CheckVar_fix_dead_pixels.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="W")


# functions

    def open(self):
        self.filename_open = tkFileDialog.askopenfilenames(defaultextension='.*')

if __name__ == "__main__":
   d = MainWindow()
   d.mainloop()
```

If you separator you can use the `Seperator`class, i was adding the seperator to the `middle_frame` so you have more control of this widget. Now you can use `column` to set "Camera white balance" and "average white balance" side by side. The columnspan attribute defines the number of columns a widget should span. So if you have more than 2 columns update that attribute. Finally if you use `sticky` you can define on which side the widget should stay.

Comment: It would probably make more sense to put the separators _between_ the frames rather than inside one of the frames.

Comment: I like to 'manage' widgets in frames instead of letting them `pack()` into the root window. But actually it would have been smarter to put the separator in the `top_frame`. For packing the separator between the frames use: `self.sep = Separator(self, orient=HORIZONTAL)`and `self.sep.pack(fill="x", after=top_frame)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it is possible to use `grid` In any frame you wish
2. Yes, it is possible to place "Camera white balance" and "average white balance" in the same row.
3. The reason the code runs forever without displaying anything is because you are using both grid (for the separator) and pack (for the frames). They both have the same parent so you can only use one or the other.

To get things to align you should read the documentation to learn about all of the options available when calling `grid` and `pack`. These options allow you to center itemsm or align them alon an edge, control padding, and so on.

Comment: Thanks @bryan Oakley. Do you have some example to understand better? if i change self.sep.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=5, pady=5) with self.sep.pack() the line is positioned under  "Fix dead pixels"" and not under the button "Input raw image file"