# Is there any better method to manage place in Tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Now I only use the method `place()` to manipulate objects place. Like this:

```
self.s_date_label = Label(self, text = 'Start Date: ')
self.s_date_label.place(x=0,y=0)
self.start_date = Entry(self, bd=1)
self.start_date.place(x=70,y=0)   
self.s_date_label2 = Label(self, text = 'example: 20160101'
self.s_date_label2.place(x=130,y=0)
```

However, I believe this is a stupid way.

Because when I have to control a lot of objects in the same line. All I can do is only control them by the parameter `x` in `place()`.

Is there any better method to manage the location of objects?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846063/what-is-a-better-tkinter-geometry-manager-than-grid .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two alternatives are to use `grid` and `pack`

### grid

`grid` is best if you need a table-like layout using rows and columns. You can specify specific cells, and you can have items span multiple rows and/or multiple columns.

For example:

```
l1 = tk.Label(parent, text="Username:")
l2 = tk.Label(parent, text='Password:")
username_entry = tk.Entry(parent)
password_entry = tk.Entry(parent)

l1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e")
username_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ew")
l2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="e")
password_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="ew")

parent.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
parent..grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

For more information see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm

### pack

`pack` is great for laying out objects in horizontal or vertical groups. `pack` is great for toolbars, and and is often what I use for the overall layout where you have a toolbar at the top, a statusbar at the bottom, and content in the middle.

For example:

```
toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(root)
statusbar_frame = tk.Frame(root)
content_frame = tk.Frame(root)

toolbar_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
statusbar_frame.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
content_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

For more information see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm

### Mixing pack and grid

You can (and should) use both `grid` and `pack` in the same application. However, you cannot use both on widgets that share a common parent.

This won't work because `toolbar` and `statusbar` have the same parent:

```
toolbar = tk.Frame(root)
sstatusbar = tk.Frame(root)

toolbar.grid(...)
statusbar.pack(...)
```

This will work, because `toolbar` and `save_button` have different parents.

```
toolbar = tk.Frame(root)
save_button = tk.Button(toolbar, ...)

toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
save_button.pack(side="left")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `grid()` method to place the objects in a layout.

With the help of padding (`padx` and `pady`) you can also space your objects.

For details check: [grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) and [sample](http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/layout/)